# Distinct count is not exact when calculating running total

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to calculate a running total over a distinct count, but the figures I get out are not exact.

This is my dax code:

```
Running Total = 
VAR MaxDate = Max('Dates'[Date])
VAR Result = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Figures'[Order Number]),
        FILTER( ALLSELECTED(Date), Dates[Date] <= MaxDate)
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

My data comes out like this:

```
Date    DistinctCount Running Total  Expected Running Total
1/5     36            36             36
2/5     76            109            112
3/5     80            189            192
4/5     66            254            258
5/5     95            348            353
6/5     111           456            464
```

Expected Running Total is just my manually calculatated column.
Alle numbers are integers.

Why the difference between Running total and Expected?

Comment: Can you share a .pbix?

Comment: @Kresten Hello. Your MaxDate variable should take the value from the fact table, not from the date table. Also, ALLSELECTED() is quite an intricate and complex function. ALL(Date) would be much better in Filter function?